# How to call a variable or function inside of another JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am using this JavaScript Spinner/loader project http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

I have some code on a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/9pBsr/ that shows my progress, it may look like overkill with all the functions I have but I have stripped out all the non-relevent stuff for this post.  So if you can help me, please leave all the structure the same way as it is.

Now my Problem.  The library I am using has this code to show the spinner

```
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

The documentation says to kill and hide the spinner to run a `stop` function on the `Spinner` but the way my code is structured, I am not sure how to access it because I keep getting errors like

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of undefined`

My end result is to be able to call this and have it stop/kill the spinner...

```
zPanel.loader.hideLoader()
```

Here is my JavaScript but all the JS and HTML is on this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/9pBsr/

Please help me to get the `zPanel.loader.hideLoader()` function to call the `zPanel.loader.buildSpinner()` functions `Spinner.stop()`

```
var zPanel = {

    init: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            zPanel.loader.init();
        });
    },



    loader: {

        init: function() {
            //Bind zloader to button click
            $('#button').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.showLoader();
            });

            $('#hidebutton').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.hideLoader();
            });
        },

        showLoader: function() {
            //Show Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").show();
                zPanel.loader.buildSpinner();
            });
        },

        hideLoader: function() {
            //Hide  Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").hide();

                // This is the function that is not working yet
                //zPanel.loader.spinner('stop');
                zPanel.loader.buildSpinner.spinner.stop();
            });
        },

        buildSpinner: function() {

            var opts = {
              lines: 9, // The number of lines to draw
              length: 11, // The length of each line
              width: 13, // The line thickness
              radius: 40, // The radius of the inner circle
              corners: 0.4, // Corner roundness (0..1)
              rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
              color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
              speed: 1, // Rounds per second
              trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
              shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
              hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
              className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
              zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              top: 200, // Top position relative to parent in px
              left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };

            var target = document.getElementById('zloader_content');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

            // I need to call spinner.stop() some how from my function above name hideLoader()

        },

    }

};

zPanel.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your spinner a member of your zPanel.

```
var zPanel = {

    spinner:null,

    init: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            zPanel.loader.init();
        });
    },



    loader: {

        init: function() {
            //Bind zloader to button click
            $('#button').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.showLoader();
            });

            $('#hidebutton').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.hideLoader();
            });
        },

        showLoader: function() {
            //Show Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").show();
                zPanel.loader.buildSpinner();
            });
        },

        hideLoader: function() {
            //Hide  Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").hide();
                zPanel.spinner.stop();
            });
        },

        buildSpinner: function() {

            var opts = {
              lines: 9, // The number of lines to draw
              length: 11, // The length of each line
              width: 13, // The line thickness
              radius: 40, // The radius of the inner circle
              corners: 0.4, // Corner roundness (0..1)
              rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
              color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
              speed: 1, // Rounds per second
              trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
              shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
              hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
              className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
              zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              top: 200, // Top position relative to parent in px
              left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };

            var target = document.getElementById('zloader_content');
            zPanel.spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

            // I need to call spinner.stop() some how from my function above name hideLoader()

        },

    }

};

zPanel.init();
```

Comment: damn you beat me by a couple seconds!

Answer (score 1):

Save the spinner to a variable attached to zPanel, then use that reference to stop the spinner,
How about this:

```
var zPanel = {

    init: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            zPanel.loader.init();
        });
    },



    loader: {

        init: function() {
            //Bind zloader to button click
            $('#button').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.showLoader();
            });

            $('#hidebutton').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.hideLoader();
            });
        },

        showLoader: function() {
            //Show Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").show();
                //showDiv();
                zPanel.spinner = zPanel.loader.buildSpinner();
            });
        },

        hideLoader: function() {
            //Hide  Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").hide();
                //showDiv();
                //zPanel.loader.spinner('stop');
                zPanel.spinner.stop();
            });
        },

        buildSpinner: function() {

            var opts = {
              lines: 9, // The number of lines to draw
              length: 11, // The length of each line
              width: 13, // The line thickness
              radius: 40, // The radius of the inner circle
              corners: 0.4, // Corner roundness (0..1)
              rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
              color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
              speed: 1, // Rounds per second
              trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
              shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
              hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
              className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
              zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              top: 200, // Top position relative to parent in px
              left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };
            //var target = document.getElementById('zloader');
            var target = document.getElementById('zloader_content');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

            return spinner;
        },

    }

};

zPanel.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

zPanel is an object. The functions in zPanel only use their own variables. To be able to call the spinner object just create a spinner property in zPanel and let all functions use this property:

```
var zPanel = {

    spinner: null,  //Notice the property!

    init: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            zPanel.loader.init();
        });
    },



    loader: {

        init: function() {
            //Bind zloader to button click
            $('#button').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.showLoader();
            });

            $('#hidebutton').click(function() {
                zPanel.loader.hideLoader();
            });
        },

        showLoader: function() {
            //Show Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").show();
                //showDiv();
                zPanel.loader.buildSpinner();
            });
        },

        hideLoader: function() {
            var self = this; //Create a variable that is accesable within the fadeIn
            //Hide  Spinning Loader
            $('#zloader_overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $("#zloader").hide();
                //showDiv();
                //Below code has changed!!
                self.spinner('stop');
                zPanel.loader.buildSpinner.spinner.stop();
            });
        },

        buildSpinner: function() {

            var opts = {
              lines: 9, // The number of lines to draw
              length: 11, // The length of each line
              width: 13, // The line thickness
              radius: 40, // The radius of the inner circle
              corners: 0.4, // Corner roundness (0..1)
              rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
              color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
              speed: 1, // Rounds per second
              trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
              shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
              hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
              className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
              zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              top: 200, // Top position relative to parent in px
              left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };
            //var target = document.getElementById('zloader');
            var target = document.getElementById('zloader_content');

            //Below line has changed!!!
            this.spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

            //if(spinStart == 'stop'){
            //    zPanel.loader.spinner.spinner.stop();
            //}

        },

    }
```